# CentOS 7: Postfix logs got cleared when running history -c. How can I investigate what happened the day the log was cleared?

Tags: centos, postfix, logging, log-files

By default, running `history -c` has no way of also deleting `/var/mail/maillog`, right?

How can I investigate what happened the day the log was cleared, or (by definition) when the new maillog was started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two events are not in a causal relationship; `history` manipulates the history list, not any service log files.

Check your `logrotate` configuration.

```
logrotate --debug /etc/logrotate.conf
```

There is a chance the older logs are in `/var/mail/maillog.1` unless you have `rotate 0` in your configuration for the path.

Also, the log file is typically at `/var/log/mail.log` or `/var/log/maillog`, whereas `/var/mail` is a directory for the `mbox` files.